# Pandas Groupby combining columns for aggregating

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like below. I what to find the sum of TOTACTVAL value for each OWNNAME(1,2)

```
    OWNNAME1     OWNNAME2   TOTACTVAL
0     Fred       John           100
1     Scott       Fred          200
2     John         Pascal        150
3     Connor      Fred          50
```

The result I expect is sorted by TOTACTVAL

```
Name    TOTACTVAL
Fred    350
John    250
Scott   200
Pascal  150
Connor  50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set index on 'TOTACTVAL' and unstack to level -1 and reset index

```
newdf = df.set_index('TOTACTVAL').unstack(-1).reset_index()
```

Rename the unstacked column

```
newdf.rename(columns={0: 'Name'}, inplace=True)
```

Group, Sum, and Sort. The `reset_index` is needed to transform the resulting Series (with `Name` index) back to a DataFrame with two columns (`Name`, `TOTACTVAL`)

```
newdf = newdf.groupby('Name')['TOTACTVAL'].apply(sum).reset_index()
newdf.sort('TOTACTVAL', ascending=False)
```

This prints:

```
     Name  TOTACTVAL
1    Fred        350
2    John        250
4   Scott        200
3  Pascal        150
0  Connor         50
```

Comment: That worked great, Thanks! One thing I had to change and maybe you can comment on this for myself and others. The DataFrame actually has many more columns. I had to create a new df containing only the columns in my example for this to work.

Comment: ah yes, unstacking would yield different result if there are more columns, so it is necessary to subset the dataframe before the first step provided in the answer, which assumes a dataframe posted by the OP.

Comment: I am reading the docs for unstacking. Is it possible to include an additional column to sum, returning an additional column?